# Seeding database Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and creating seed data for a test database. All is working except for one problem.

Some of my classes check for a duplicate ID before adding an object to a list. This is a typical pattern:

```
   private Assignment FindAssignment(VideoCourse course) {
        Assignment assignment = assignments.Find(x => x.Course.Id == course.Id);
        if (assignment == null) {
            assignment = new Assignment(this, course);
            assignments.Add(assignment);
        }
        return assignment;
    }
```

This fails (I can't add more than one course) in my Seed override because `course.Id` is 0 for all courses until they've been saved to the database.

I've tried calling `SaveChanges()` at multiple places in the code but that really messes with the context and results in other objects not being saved.

So the question - how do I get objects saved to the database so their Id's can be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the easiest way to solve the problem was to assign objects their Id in code, rather than waiting for the database to do it.